# Handling PersistentVolumeClaim in DaemonSet

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pvc

I have a `DaemonSet` that creates flink task manager pods, one per each node.

### Nodes

Say I have two nodes

- node-A
- node-B

### Pods

the daemonSet would create

- pod-A on node-A
- pod-B on node-B

### Persistent Volume Claim

- I am on AKS and want to use `azure-disk` for Persistent Storage
- According to the docs : [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disks-dynamic-pv ]

  - an azure disk can be associated on to single node

say I create

- pvc-A for pv-A attached to node-A
- pvc-B for pv-B attached to node-B

### Question

How can I associate **pod-A** on **node-A** to use **pcv-A** ?

## UPDATE:

After *much* googling, i stumbled upon that it might be better/cleaner to use a StatefulSet instead. This does mean that you won't get the features available to you via DaemonSet like one pod per node.

> https://medium.com/@zhimin.wen/persistent-volume-claim-for-statefulset-8050e396cc51

Comment: you need a cloud native storage backend where the PVC is independent of where the real disk is.

Answer (score 8):

If you use a persistentVolumeClaim in your daemonset definition, and the persistentVolumeClaim is satisfied with PV with the type of `hostPath`, your daemon pods will read and write to the local path defined by `hostPath`. This behavior will help you separate the storage using one PVC.

This might not directly apply to your situation but I hope this helps whoever searching for something like a "volumeClaimTemplate for DaemonSet" in the future.

Using the same example as cookiedough (thank you!)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: x
  namespace: x
  labels:
    k8s-app: x
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: x
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: x
    spec:
      ...
      containers:
      - name: x
        ...
        volumeMounts:
        - name: volume
          mountPath: /var/log
      volumes:
      - name: volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: my-pvc
```

And that PVC is bound to a PV (Note that there is only one PVC and one PV!)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    type: local
  name: mem
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /tmp/mem
    type: Directory
  storageClassName: standard
status: {}
```

Your daemon pods will actually use `/tmp/mem` on each node. (There's at most 1 daemon pod on each node so that's fine.)

Answer (score -1):

The way to attach a PVC to your DaemonSet pod is not any different than how you do it with other types of pods. Create your PVC and mount it as a volume onto the pod.

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-pvc
  namespace: x
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

This is what the DaemonSet manifest would look like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: x
  namespace: x
  labels:
    k8s-app: x
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: x
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: x
    spec:
      ...
      containers:
      - name: x
        ...
        volumeMounts:
        - name: volume
          mountPath: /var/log
      volumes:
      - name: volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: my-pvc
```

Comment: an azure disk can be associated on to single node! so i need a way to have multiple pvcs